# jquery and laravel append form

Tags: jquery, laravel

My problem is that using append () I add form that I have in a variable, but this form does not work, that is, by clicking in input submit nothing happens. My code:

```
var myForm = '<div class="form-append-note d-block">\n' +
        '        {!! Form::open() !!}\n' +
        '            <div class="form-group">\n' +
        '                    <textarea class="blue-inp note-textarea" maxlength="512" name="note"></textarea>\n' +
        '                </div>\n' +
        '            <div class="d-flex">\n' +
        '                    {!! Form::submit('Add note',['class'=>'btn btn-save-blue']) !!}\n' +
        '                </div>\n' +
        '        {!! Form::close() !!}\n' +
        '    </div>';


$('#myBtn').on('click', function(e)
    {
$('.page).append(myForm);
});
```

Comment: `$('.page).append(myForm);` is a syntax error, for one.

Comment: where is class .page you cant put pls

Comment: For two, while it can work using `{!! !!}` blade syntax in JS, you might run across errors. For this, why not use `<form>`, `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-save-blue">Add Note</button>` and `</form>`?